# Función no muestra nada

Tags: c++

Hola he creado una función con la cual quiero mostrar el contenido de los métodos de una clase. Lo tengo todo hecho y el programa compila pero no muestra nada, ¿qué me estoy dejando atrás? Quiero mostrar el contenido de la clase *temazo*.

**Temazo.h**

```
#ifndef TEMAZO_H
#define TEMAZO_H
#include <string>

class Temazo{
public:
    Temazo();
    Temazo(std::string titulo, std::string interprete,  int duracion, int puntuacion);
    Temazo(const Temazo &orig);

    void setTitulo(std::string titulo);
    std::string getTitulo() const;

    void setInterprete(std::string interprete);
    std::string getInterprete() const;

    void setDuracion(int duracion);
    int getDuracion() const;

    int getPuntuacion() const;



    ~Temazo();     

private:
    std::string titulo;
    std::string interprete;
    int duracion;
    int puntuacion;

};

#endif /* TEMAZO_H */
```

**Temazo.cpp**

```
#include "Temazo.h"

Temazo::Temazo(std::string titulo, std::string interprete, int duracion, int puntuacion)
        : titulo(titulo),
        interprete(interprete),
        duracion(duracion),
        puntuacion(puntuacion){

}

Temazo::Temazo(const Temazo& orig)
        : titulo(orig.titulo),
        interprete(orig.interprete),
        duracion(orig.duracion),
        puntuacion(orig.puntuacion){

}

Temazo::~Temazo(){

}

void Temazo::setTitulo(std::string titulo){
    this->titulo = titulo;
}

std::string Temazo::getTitulo() const{
    return titulo;
}

void Temazo::setInterprete(std::string interprete){
    this->interprete = interprete;
}

std::string Temazo::getInterprete() const{
    return interprete;
}

void Temazo::setDuracion(int duracion){
    this->duracion = duracion;
}

int Temazo::getDuracion() const{
    return duracion;
}

int Temazo::getPuntuacion() const{
    return puntuacion;
}
```

La función la tengo creada en un módulo externo llamado *funciones*

**Funciones.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCIONES_H
#define FUNCIONES_H
#include "Fecha.h"
#include "Garito.h"
#include "Temazo.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace funciones{

    void mostrarTemazo(const Temazo& temazo);

}
#endif /* FUNCIONES_H */
```

**Funciones.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "funciones.h"


void funciones::mostrarTemazo(const Temazo& t){

   std::cout <<"Interprete: "<<t.getInterprete()<<std::endl;
   std::cout <<"Titulo: "<<t.getTitulo()<<std::endl;
   std::cout <<"Duracion: "<<t.getDuracion()<<std::endl;
   std::cout <<"Puntaucion"<<t.getPuntuacion()<<std::endl;  

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Temazo t("Nirvana", "Smell Like Teen Spirit", 205, 10);
    void mostrarTemazo(const Temazo& t);

    return (0);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia esto:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Temazo t("Nirvana", "Smell Like Teen Spirit", 205, 10);
    void mostrarTemazo(const Temazo& t);

    return (0);

}
```

por esto:

```
#include "funciones.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Temazo t("Nirvana", "Smell Like Teen Spirit", 205, 10);
    funciones::mostrarTemazo(t);

    return (0);

}
```

La función ya la has declarado en la cabecera, luego no tienes que volver a declararla sino, simplemente, realizar la llamada correspondiente.

Como resulta que la función se encuentra en el espacio de nombres `funciones` no debes olvidarte de dicho espacio o el compilador no encontrará la función.